# Xubuntu battery alarm

Tags: command-line, cron, battery

I need to write a script but was beyond my capacity. So I ask a help to those more able in the command line.

I need a script that checks the percentage of battery every minute and sounds a signal if it falls below a certain threshold.

I find my percentage with the following command:

> upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1| grep -E "percentage"

I would like it to be played a signal when it falls below 25%.

I would use this script only to "discharge" sessions, and the ideal would be a long command line that would be more convenient because closing the terminal will also interrupt the battery check.

Question:

- Will using crontab and closing the terminal also close the cron process that is open? Is it better to use a `do while` loop?

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Answer (score 1):

*I am sure the following script isn't optimal and it might even have mistakes I can't see myself. I'm very amateur at programming and I only do it as a hobby.* **I will be happy to accept criticisms or suggestions! :)**

### Script using `acpi`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# A script to make an alarm go off at desired battery thresholds


### Variables

BAT=$(acpi | grep -o [[:digit:]][[:digit:]] | head -1)
LOW_LVL=35
CHARG=$(acpi | grep -o "Charging")
CHARGING=0

### Functions

charging()
{
    ### Checks wether the computer is charging (1) or not (0) 
    if [ "$CHARG 1" = "Charging 1" ]; then
        CHARGING=1
    else CHARGING=0 
     fi
    echo $CHARGING
}

alarm_connect()
{
    notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/status/battery-low.png "Battery under 35%" "Charge it"
    paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga
}


### Main

while true
do
    if [  $(charging) = 0   ]; then
        if [ $BAT -le $LOW_LVL ]; then
            $(alarm_connect)
             fi

    sleep 1m
done
```

### Script using `upower`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# A script to make an alarm go off at desired battery thresholds

### Variables

BAT=$(upower -i $(upower -e | grep 'BAT') | grep -E "state|to\ full|percentage" | grep -o [[:digit:]][[:digit:]])
LOW_LVL=25
CHARG=$(upower -i $(upower -e | grep 'BAT') | grep -E "state|to\ full|percentage" | grep -o "\ charging")
CHARGING=0

### Functions

charging()
{
    ### Checks wether the computer is charging (1) or not (0) 
    if [ "$CHARG" = " charging" ]; then
        CHARGING=1
    else CHARGING=0 
     fi
    echo $CHARGING
}

alarm_connect()
{
            paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga
}

### Main

while true
do
    if [  $(charging) = 0   ]; then
        if [ $BAT -le $LOW_LVL ]; then
            $(alarm_connect)
        fi
    fi

    sleep 60
done
```

You can replace as desired:

- The variables `LOW_LVL` to modify the battery % you wish to have the alarm go off at.
- The sound and icon that appear with the `notify-send`, just check the path to them and you can find a diverse number of options there.
- The `sleep` time. Example: `sleep 60` = `sleep 1m`.

---

> *Will using crontab and closing the terminal also close the cron process that is open?*

No, closing the terminal won't stop the `cron` job. So if that's how you want to use it, run it from terminal and close it when you are done with it.

Comment: Thanks for the script! Before installing `acpi` (I want avoid problems) I tried to use upower, but I can not insert its contents into the variable. I'm pretty well versed in visual programming language, but I do not know anything about the syntax of bash. I understand fully the logic of your program, but I have extreme difficulty to change even a comma X- (so I wonder if you could kindly tell me how to use `upower` with the variable. Thank you!

Comment: @Lucius1202 You are welcome! Installing `acpi` shouldn't cause any problems, but in case you want to be safe, I added the option to use the script with `upower`.

Comment: M.Becerra you are very kind! I tested the script with upower and there is a syntax error in the two nested loops, missing a "DO"?
The error is (translating from Italian): `syntax error near token unespected "done"`
`line 43: `done '`
Sorry if I take advantage of your kindness!

Comment: @Lucius1202 I do it happily. It wasn't a "do", I forgot to end and if loop inside the while loop. Please try it again and let's see if we can make it work :)

Comment: @Lucius1202 Could you try the new version? I'd like to hear back how it works fr you now :)

Comment: Excuse me for a long time but the work took me completely, I'm trying the script right now but unfortunately only works if the battery is charging, if you are discharging any rate I put in low_level variable does not report anything, the terminal does not give error messages, just a wait cursor. Do you have any idea? As always thank you for your kindness.

Comment: The command:  `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1| grep -E "percentage"` give me  `state: discharging`. I say if it is a problem with `grep -o "charging"`. I hope help.